# Как удалить перенос строки между определенными символами в Notepad++?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Как удалить перенос строки между определенными символами в Notepad++?

Есть, например, регулярное выражение `Слово1([\s\S]*?)Слово2`, которое заменить все содержимое между Слово1 и Слово2 и заменит его на указанное знаение. 
Имеется ли что-либо похожее, что удалит переносы строк между указанными словами, но оставит содержимое неизменным?

Comment: Пробовали вместо `\s\S` поставить `\n`?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте требования к выражению, а также пару примеров с желаемым результатом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот можно заменить все переносы строк между словами `hello` и `world` на `42`, если между словами 0+ последовательных переносов строк.

Найденное этим:

```
(hello)\n*(world)
```

заменить вот этим:

```
$142$2
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/MJM6Nl/1/

> hello
>
> world
>
> 123
>
> world
>
> hello
>
> world

станет

> hello42world
>
> 123
>
> world
>
> hello42world

Comment: [Вот тут](https://regex101.com/r/55zxIW/1) ваше выражение уже не удаляет переносы строк. Кстати, выражение автора вопроса найдёт те же совпадения, что и ваше, так что вряд ли речь только символе LF между двумя словами.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew если понимать условие как "заменить каждый перенос строки в тексте между двумя словами", то да, не заменит. Я понял его как "между 2 словами есть только 0+ переносов строк, заменить их все вместе на какое-то значение". Уточнил применимость ответа